# sql tutorial script error

Tags: mysql, sql

The SQL text that it tells you to copy and paste into phpMyAdmin's SQL page from [this](http://www.unifycommunity.com/wiki/index.php?title=Server_Side_Highscores#SQL_-_score.sql) tutorial gives me the error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 6
```

This is the script:

```
CREATE TABLE `scores` (
   `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   `name` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'anonymous',
   `score` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
)
TYPE=MyISAM;
```

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Nothing. That should work. Your IDE is probably acting up. Have you tried another MySQL client?

Comment: Just maybe try replacing `TYPE` by `ENGINE`, or omitting that entire line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `ENGINE=MyISAM` instead of `TYPE=MyISAM`.

Comment: Indeed. TYPE has been deprecated for quite some time, [but was removed/added back in again/removed again/... a few times](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=17501).

Comment: great, thanks. Out of interest, what does this line do?

Comment: You can read about different storage engines here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-engines.html. Basically, the standard storage is now InnoDB. MyISAM is old, it does not allow foreign keys and other useful things. Though it may be faster in some cases.

Comment: should I just change it to InnoDB? Also, if I omit this line will it be InnoDB anyway?

Comment: The engine you use should be a conscious choice. But if you don't really care, I would suggest using InnoDB, because it's more feature-rich. If you omit this line, the engine will be set to default engine which is InnoDB for MySQL >= 5.5 and MyISAM for MySQL < 5.5.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. TYPE  is not work for MyISAM.

```
**TYPE** must be **ENGINE** .
```

This is common problem!